# How to append 3 parameters in select box in blade in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want three parameters in the select box on Blade I correct in Laravel.

`Model`:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'hotel_id', 'name', 'desc', 'capacity', 'status' ,...
];
```

`Function`:

```
public function scopeGetRooms($request, $id)
{
    $roomsList = $request
        -> where('hotel_id', '=', $id)
        -> select(DB::raw('concat(name, " / ", desc, " / ", capacity) as main'), 'id')
        -> lists('main', 'id')
        -> all();
    return $roomsList;
}
```

‍`blade`:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    {{ Form::select('room', $roomsList ,null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>
```

The problem is `Function`:

```
-> select(DB::raw('concat(name, " / ", desc, " / ", capacity) as main'), 'id')
-> lists('main', 'id')
```

I want it displayed:

```
<select class="form-control" name="room">
    <option value="1"> 1 queen / Only 2 rooms left on our site! / 1 people </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 queen / Only 1 rooms left on our site! / 2 people </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 queen / Only 1 rooms left on our site! / 3 people </option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what part you are having trouble with.  What's it not doing that you need it to do?  Are you getting an error?  Try removing the `->all()` portion.

Comment: @user3158900 Thank you, i remove `->all()` But the following error: `QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: `

Comment: Please tell us  explicitly how you call the specified function and what the exact problem is

Comment: @nXu, Thank you for the help you, this problem code is: `-> select(DB::raw('concat(name, " / ", desc, " / ", capacity) as main'), 'id')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood my mistake,

Add a Table name to the first of each field.

My table name is `rooms`.

```
-> select(DB::raw('concat(rooms.name, " / ", rooms.desc, " / ", capacity) as main'), 'rooms.id')
-> lists('main', 'id')
```